# which is the appropriate sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Querying need database on product code. 
I use a bar code reader and the code is internal, so if read with the reader for example be of the form "S181002 $ M", so it would be stored with it.

The problem is, if the user enters "by hand" the code, it is only "S181002" and so to then look in the database with the code "S181002 $ M" would not work.

What would be the appropriate sql query?

Use laravel preferably, but could accommodate any request.

I tried this:

```
$articles = DB :: table ('articles') -> where ('code', 'LIKE', '%' $ code '%'..) -> get ();
```

But clearly "S181002 $ M" is not a substring or the same string as "S181002"

Can you help?

Note: I would need to avoid data preprocessing before alamacenarlo eg delete "$ M" as it will handle various types of codes.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you say that the code has multiple pattern in length, chars and number. Is at least the suffix ` $ M` always the same when you need the reader? In other words: Is it sufficed always to remove a substring ` $ M` at the end of the string (if exists)?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the code will always be 7 characters long, you can do:

```
SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE code = SUBSTRING('S181002 $ M', 1, 7);
```

Alternatively, if you know ' $ M' will always be the code suffix:

```
SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE code = REPLACE('S181002 $ M', ' $ M', '');
```

Comment: The problem with certain products so the code, others are just numbers or use another pattern. Rather seek a general way, as a regular expression suitable for a product code. Thank you!